# Copy Object in C++

Tags: c++, object

```
    class Item
    {
        string sItemName;
        int iQt, iPrice;

    public:
        Item(string, int, int);
        int getPrice(int);
     };


    Item o_FindItem;        

    int ItemCSVImport::GetItem(char* cItemName)
    {
        o_FindItem = (m_ItemsMap.find(cItemName)->second);
        return 1;
     }
```

The above code work fine in the first time. But when I try to call the same method for the second time the first line inside the method gives an segmentation fault. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: What is `o_FindItem`? What is `m_ItemsMap`? Are you doing anything between the two `GetItem()` calls? Are you using the same `cItemName`?

Comment: Perhaps you should check the [value of the iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/) before dereferencing it

Comment: create a Minimal Compilable Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably that `cItemName` is not found.  To fix it, try something like this:

```
int ItemCSVImport::GetItem(char* cItemName)
{
    auto it = m_ItemsMap.find(cItemName);
    if (it != m_ItemsMap.end()) {
        o_FindItem = it->second;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I get the same error in it = m_ItemsMap.find(cItemName); line. Do we need to clean the object before assigning again?

Comment: Check if `cItemName == NULL`.  If so you must return early, before calling `find()`, probably.

Comment: @JohnZwinck No, it's legal for you to use a null pointer value as a key in a map. That would not cause an access violation unless the map is using something other than the default `std::less` implementation as the comparing functor and this hypothetical custom comparer doesn't check its arguments.

Comment: @cdhowie std::string constructor will throw exception with nullptr argument, http://ideone.com/umS5fU

Comment: @DmitriSosnik Right, so it depends on the type of `m_ItemsMap`, which we haven't been provided.